# Are users notified by the site when their answer gets deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

When an answer doesn't match the site's requirements, one should follow the following process (granted they have enough reputation to do so):

- Flag the answer with the appropriate reason,
- (Hopefully) leave a comment to warn the answerer that their answer doesn't fit as is and should be edited to match the requirements,
- Vote to delete.

Sometimes there are no comments left under answers and they eventually got deleted without further explanation.

In such cases, are the users informed by some notification that their answer got deleted?

I'm asking because AFAIK one's not notified when their question gets closed so, I was wondering whether the deleted Q/A process follows the same rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Actually, no.

Users won't get notified of their deleted answer.

From [this Main meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/321725) for [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/321725),

> **Posts**
>
> - "answer"
>
>   - Another user answers one of your questions, or a question on which you have an active bounty.
> - "question migrated", "answer migrated"
>
>   - One of your posts is migrated to another site.
> - "comment"
>
>   - Another user comments on one of your posts.
>   - Another user sends you a comment reply.
> - "notice on answer", "notice on question"
>
>   - A moderator adds a post notice to one of your posts.
> - "edit suggested"
>
>   - Another user suggests an edit to your post.
> - "question edited", "answer edited", "code edited on question", "code edited on answer"
>
>   - Another user makes a substantive edit to your post.

Although, user may notice the rep change and can find which answers are deleted via [recently deleted answers](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/user-id) link (Note: replace "user-id" with your which is a number you can see in the final URL [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/current)).

Comment: Thanks for answering. JFYK, the link you provided is broken (or maybe it's only available for mods?)

Comment: Just replace the user-id with your user ID (4550) and it will work. (Works only for your own deleted posts)