# Why has my answer been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I answered a question ([How to schedule meetups effectively?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/23323/26654)) on how to schedule a meeting effectively. [My answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23336/11811) was later deleted. Why was it removed?

Image for those with lower rep:

> [image: deleted answer]

Comment: To view your recently deleted answers, see [this relevant meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3564/29). In your case, [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/26654).

Comment: @AJ Thanks, but the link (the one with the user ID) do not work. It says "page not found".

Comment: Did you visit [this link](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/26654)?

Comment: @AJ Yes, it says "page not found". I am using the app, in case that's relevant?

Comment: Actually, you have to access it via computer.

Comment: @AJ Ok, thanks, I will try it later.

Comment: I've added information about your answer to the post. If you don't want this public like that, feel free to remove it (or edit further).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of the people who voted to delete your answer.

I felt it was a good start for an answer but that it was still lacking some details which would make it fit our [quality criteria](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3271/21067).

That is why I voted the way I did and I assume the other people felt the same too.

If you wish it to be undeleted, you could add the additional details I talked about in my comments and I'll be sure to vote to undelete :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) But as I replied in a comment, I just don't think that these details are relevant: Scheduling the meetup via phone (as opposed to writing back-and-forth) is all it takes in my experience. Whether there is chitchat before asking is irrelevant, agreeing on a place, too, in my experience. Therefore I don't see why I should add details that imo don't add value. Also when you state that details are missing, do you have some backup for that claim, i.e. backup that additional details do matter in this context? And which quality criteria exactly did my answer not meet?

Comment: @simplemind IPS generally takes the view that more details are better - and if certain details *aren't* relevant, it's also good to spell that out explicitly, instead of hoping readers will assume you didn't address it on purpose vs. just overlooking or forgetting to explain it. As far as the "quality criteria", AElis linked to a relevant FAQ answer, but [this post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-ips-stack-exchange) goes into more details about backing up answers.

Comment: @EmC ok, thanks :)

Comment: The question didn't mention that several persons were involved. Actually, the example in the question keeps speaking about "the other person". I don't think it should have been canceled. It was an answer, maybe a partial answer, but still an answer. The accepted, upvoted answer only considers a context with only two people but hasn't been canceled.